# SQL Server Reporting Services - cannot authenticate through URL on the same machine as SSRS server

Tags: reporting-services

I am accessing SSRS reports (SQL Server 2016) through URL to embed them in my application in an iFrame. When I access SSRS reports remotely, i.e from different computer I can authenticate and display the reports.

In my iFrame source I put:

```
http://example.com:4000/path_to_ReportServer/report_name
```

And that works fine when I deploy my app to stage server. All the SSRS reports load with no problem at all.

However I develop on the same PC as my SSRS report server resides, and when I am on it I have to change all the links in iFrames to:

```
http://computername:4000/path_to_ReportServer/report_name
```

edit: originally I wrote here that I use localhost, but actual I meant computer name.

If I try to run my app from VS on my dev machine and I do not change the domain to computer name I wont be able to authenticate at all. It just keeps asking me for the same credentials over and over again.

I've checked the ReportServerService log, and I see this as a last line when I try to log in:

```
library!DefaultDomain!3bd0!11/21/2016-12:52:36:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: Invalid PBI Configuration, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
```

I looked for this problem extensively, and I only find MS configuration tutorial but no one having similar issue to mine.

I have checked the usual culprits like firewall or port conflicts (but if I had any of those I would not be able to access the SSRS from any other PC, yet I can and the link doesn't work only on local machine.)

I am very new to SSRS in general so please kindly be patient with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

1. In SSRS Configuration and ensure that the Report Service and Report Management endpoints are valid (Copy the url in the hyperlink and make sure it opens on your local host.)
2. In SSRS Configuration and ensure that the Report Service Database has been properly deployed.
3. Remove any custom modules/assemblies you have applied to the default behavior from the ssrs web config (Custom Security).

I think you have applied changes to ssrs's web config in order to have it load assemblies for your custom security, custom datasourse/dataset, custom render format and fat fingered the config somehow.

Comment: Hey Ross, thanks for the list. I will go over it slowly this evening and will report back here - it is very likely that i messed up something as you say :) but you have just given me places to look.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a [same-origin-policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) error, which wikipedia states as `under the policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin.`

The fix is to implement the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) metatag, like so:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/
```